# Sorting cells in rows to match respective column headers in R

Tags: r, sorting

I'm trying to sort the cell value in multiple rows to match the value of column headers.

What it looks like:

```
A B C D E 
---------
D
A C 
C E
B D E
E
```

What I want it to look like:

```
A B C D E 
---------
      D
A   C 
    C   E
  B   D E
        E
```

Any suggestions are much appreciated. Cheers.

Comment: Try `t(apply(df1, 1, function(x) x[match(names(x), x)]))`

Comment: Try *align* instead of *sort*.

Comment: Thanks akrun that solution worked like a charm.